# Why is my global variable inside a function not working?

Tags: scope, global-variables, python-3.7, local-variables

I'm trying to get a simple variable inside a function from a global perspective.

For example:  `combaso` variable inside the `show_data` func. 
But it's not working.

```py
#Get state input
def show_data():
    global combaso
    combaso = 'Lol' #Variable I need.

print(combaso) #Global variable
```

Error I'm getting.

`NameError: name 'combaso' is not defined`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.